# Enable Mod Expires on Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I'd like to enable `mod_expires` on my server.

I'm using Ubuntu and Apache.

**When I try to check if the module is enabled :**

```
********:/etc/apache2$ sudo a2enmod expires
Module expires already enabled
```

**My `apache2.conf` :**

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

I have restarted apache with the command `systemctl restart apache2` but when I try to check if my website have the caching it seem's that I don't have something...

The website that I'm using to ckeck is : https://www.giftofspeed.com/cache-checker/

Do you have any idea of the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need headers module to get expires module works.

```
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

> Module expires already enabled

Did you check in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled ? Did you run a syntax check with apachectl? Did you check if the module was loaded using server-status? Did you check your logs for startup errors?

Run `httpd -M | grep expires` to see if the module will be loaded by your config.

> The website that I'm using to ckeck is : https://www.giftofspeed.com/cache-checker/

? Just use curl (with -I) or webdeveloper in your browser.

....and don't edit the supplied configuration files with your config, add them as new files.